# Identifying groups of duplicated records (TSQL)

Tags: t-sql, optimization, duplicates

I have got massive table (over 95 000 000 records) in MSSQL database

| id | configuration_id | equipment_group_id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | item3 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 6 | 2 | 100 | item3 | 30 |
| 7 | 3 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 8 | 3 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 9 | 3 | 100 | item3 | 31 |

I am going to identify duplicated group of records.

**Configuration 1 Group**

| id | configuration_id | equipment_group_id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | item3 | 30 |

**Configuration 2 Group**

| id | configuration_id | equipment_group_id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 6 | 2 | 100 | item3 | 30 |

**Configuration 3 Group**

| id | configuration_id | equipment_group_id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 3 | 100 | item1 | 10 |
| 8 | 3 | 100 | item2 | 20 |
| 9 | 3 | 100 | item3 | 31 |

- in my logic **Group 1** and **Group 2** are duplicates

  - has the same number of records
  - has the same content in fields `equipment_group_id`, `name`, `price`
- **Group 1** and **Group 3** are NOT duplicates because there is at least one different element (last record has price 31, not 30)

**How to construct a query to find all groups that are duplicated (not records) across the table?**

Answer (score 0):

Performance of this query for 95M records will probably not be ideal, but this should do the trick.

### Find Exact Matches of Groups Containing Multiple Rows

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Config

CREATE TABLE #Config 
(id int
,configuration_id int
,equipment_group_id int
,name VARCHAR(100)
,price INT
)

INSERT INTO #Config
VALUES
(1,1,100,'item1',10)
,(2,1,100,'item2',20)
,(3,1,100,'item3',30)
,(4,2,100,'item1',10)
,(5,2,100,'item2',20)
,(6,2,100,'item3',30)
,(7,3,100,'item1',10)
,(8,3,100,'item2',20)
,(9,3,100,'item3',31)


;WITH cte_ConfigCount AS (
    SELECT *,ConfigTotalRowCnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.configuration_id) /*Counts how many rows in each config*/
    FROM #Config AS A
)

SELECT 
    A.configuration_id
    ,B.configuration_id
    ,TextDescription = CONCAT('Config #',A.configuration_id,' matches Config #',B.configuration_id)
    ,A.ConfigTotalRowCnt
    ,RowsMatch = COUNT(*)
FROM cte_ConfigCount AS A
INNER JOIN cte_ConfigCount AS B
    ON A.configuration_id < B.configuration_id /*Don't join to self and only join 1 way (so don't have one row with A-B and another row with B-A)*/
    AND a.equipment_group_id = B.equipment_group_id
    AND A.name = B.name
    AND A.price = B.price
GROUP BY A.configuration_id,A.ConfigTotalRowCnt,B.configuration_id
HAVING A.ConfigTotalRowCnt = COUNT(*) /*Only return where the total row for the config matches the rows where the configs match*/
```